# How can we create our own custom dropdownButton in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to create a customised DropDownButton called 'Select Date', on clicking which a calendar should pop up in Dialog form,  from where I can select date and it should get updated in the dropdown button. 
What is the right approach to achieve this?

Since I could not find anything from Flutters side to customize its DropDownButton, I was thinking if creating a Container wrapped in Ink could exhibit similar behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extract original DropDownButton widget code and customize as you want.. Flutter is open source :D

Comment: Thanks.. I did fix it .. however i did it using the container method where i created a Container which looks similar to a DropDown and then wrapped it in InkWell.